# Flutter: animate appbar color with bottomnavigationbar

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I wonna animate my appbar color the same way as the bottomnavigationbar does with the shifting type. So the appbar and bottomnavigationbar change color together.

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  int _tabIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Dash')),
      body: Container(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _tabIndex,
        onTap: (value) => setState(() => _tabIndex = value),
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
          unselectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).unselectedWidgetColor,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.dashboard), title: Text('Dash'), backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.insert_chart), title: Text('Data'), backgroundColor: Colors.red),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.monetization_on), title: Text('Income'), backgroundColor: Colors.orange),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I do this? (I'm fairly new to flutter) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. Simply change color based on the selected index.

Here you go

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _tabIndex = 0;
  var colors = [Colors.blue, Colors.red, Colors.orange];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Dash'),
        backgroundColor: colors[_tabIndex],
      ),
      body: Container(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _tabIndex,
          onTap: (value) => setState(() => _tabIndex = value),
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
          unselectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).unselectedWidgetColor,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.dashboard),
                title: Text('Dash'),
                backgroundColor: colors[0]),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.insert_chart),
                title: Text('Data'),
                backgroundColor: colors[1]),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.monetization_on),
                title: Text('Income'),
                backgroundColor: colors[2]),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

See the live demo [here](https://dartpad.dev/7631396c99ab9b8c10ff15feddf35764).